# UDF to concatenate values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a user defined function using VBA for excel. That would concatenate a list of stores which has a x mark in that row.

```
   Store1 Store2 Store3    Concatenate
      x             x      Store1,Store3  
      x      x             tore1,Store2
      x                    Store1
```

I managed to write this vba code, but I am not sure this is the best approach. As I was tesing in on 1000 and more lines, it was quite slow. Maybe it is possible to optimise it?

**firstStore** you point where the first store starts (not the names, but the x marks,**lastStore1** the last column. **listofstores1** is the row where the store names are.

```
Function listofstores(firstStore As Range, lastStore1 As Range, listofstores1 As Range)
    Application.Volatile

    Dim offsetvalue As Integer

    offsetvalue = -(lastStore1.Row - listofstores1.Row)

    lastStore = lastStore1.Column
    Set initial = firstStore

    For i = 1 To lastStore
    If initial = "X" Or initial = "x" Then Store = initial.Offset(offsetvalue, 0)
    c = 1
    Set initial = initial.Offset(0, c)
    listofstores = listofstores & " " & Store
    Store = ""


    Next i
    End Function
```

Comment: If you have Office 2016 then you might be able to make use of the newly introduced TEXTJOIN function: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short but intricate.

1. uses `Evaluate` to return an array of matches (Store numbers v x)
2. `Filter` removes the non-matches ("V")
3. `Join` to make the string from the final array of matches

*UDF*

```
Function Getx(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range) As String
Getx = Join(Filter(Evaluate("=ÏF(" & Rng2.Address & "=""x""," & Rng1.Address & ",""V"")"), "V", False), ",")
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seems that everything is working and should performe better

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve is as below. You can do any where in sheets

```
Sub Main()
    Call getlistofstores(Range("G13:L15"), Range("G12:L12"))
End Sub

Function getlistofstores(stores As Range, listofstores As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim fullconcatstring As String
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer
    a = stores.Count / listofstores.Count
    b = listofstores.Count
    row = stores.Cells(1).row
    column = stores.Cells(1).column + (b)
    For i = 1 To a
        For j = 1 To b
            If stores.Cells(i, j) = "x" Then
                If concatstring <> "" Then
                    concatstring = concatstring & ", " & listofstores.Cells(j)
                Else
                    concatstring = listofstores.Cells(j)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        fullconcatstring = fullconcatstring & Chr(10) & Chr(11) & concatstring
        concatstring = ""
    Next i
    Call concatenateallstores(row, column, fullconcatstring)
End Function

Sub concatenateallstores(r As Integer, c As Integer, d As String)
    str1 = Split(d, Chr(10) & Chr(11))
    str2 = UBound(str1)
    For i = 1 To str2
        Cells(r, c) = str1(i)
        r = r + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]