# Excel formula to return multiple column names

Tags: excel, textjoin

I am trying to get a formula that searches each row for a "Yes". It then should list the column name(s). Some row may only have 1 yes, some may have 3 or more. I have tried searching and editing several suggestions, but cannot get the one I need. Some formulas will give me a random column name, and only 1. Other just error out.

```
Header 1    Header 2    Header 3    Header 4    List
  No          Yes        Yes           No       Header 2, Header 3
 Yes           No        Yes          Yes       Header 1, Header 3, Header 4
  No           No         No          Yes       Header 4
 Yes          Yes         No          Yes       Header 1, Header 2, Header 4
```

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: If you do not have Office 365 Excel then see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572697/udf-to-concatenate-values  If you do then look into TEXTJOIN().

Comment: it is 2013, the first one you linked is exactly what end result I want, was just hoping to not use coding as I am even worse at that lol, I will try that though now

Comment: Then you will need to use a UDF.

Comment: There is no need to use an UDF. Check my formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following UDF:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Put it in a module attached to the worksheet.

Then you would call it like any other formula with the following array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A2:D2="Yes",$A$1:$D$1,""))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

To get it with IF formulas this will return the same thing, since you only have four.  If you have more than four this would get quite long.

```
=LEFT(IF(A2="Yes",$A$1 & ",","") & IF(B2="Yes",$B$1 & ",","") & IF(C2="Yes",$C$1 & ",","") & IF(D2="Yes",$D$1 & ",",""),LEN(IF(A2="Yes",$A$1 & ",","") & IF(B2="Yes",$B$1 & ",","") & IF(C2="Yes",$C$1 & ",","") & IF(D2="Yes",$D$1 & ",",""))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: That UDF you just gave works great, exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @scott was just trying to use your UDF one a basic row with nothing special, just numbers.  All I was trying to do was combine the cells of a row and put a comma in between the values.  I keep getting the result of #Value!  The UDF from this question is the only code in the worksheet.  Does the worksheet need to be saved first?  `=textjoin(",",TRUE,A24:J24)` is what I have for a formula currently.

Comment: use this one instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell @ForwardEd

Comment: Thank you.  I will take a look at this.  I stumbled on this solution and a few other UDFs.  I was originally looking the TEXTJOINT array fomula alternative that I thought you had for 2013 users, but my google skills failed me.

Comment: @ForwardEd I do have one that is a TEXTJOINIFS(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like that:

```
    =(IF(EXACT(A2;"Yes");A1 & ", ";"")) & (IF(EXACT(B2;"Yes");B1 & ", ";""))  & (IF(EXACT(C2;"Yes");C1 & ", ";"")) & (IF(EXACT(D2;"Yes");D1 & ", ";""))
```

It will test if the cell string correspond to "Yes", if it is the case, the string written is the header, otherwise the string written is "". 
I have also concatenated with three others IF condition with & symbol.

Applying this formula on the first line of your array return the following result:

```
    header 2, header 3,
```

I thing you can improve it to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no need for an UDF**

Use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A2="Yes",A$1&", ","")&IF(B2="Yes",B$1&", ","")&IF(C2="Yes",C$1&", ","")&IF(D2="Yes",D$1&", ",""),", H","-H"),", ",""),"-H",", H")
```

`SUBSTITUTE`s are a (possibly overkill) way of removing the trailing `", "`, only if needed.
Copy down in as many rows as needed.

I meant to write an array formula, which would work for any number of columns without explicitly writing each one, but apparently `CONCATENATE` does not work with array formulas.