# String comparison between two cells containing text but one containing multiple delimiters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-comparison, text-comparison, vba

I wish to compare two cells in excel which contain similar text but one containing different delimiters in it. I want to ignore the delimiters while comparing the strings.

Eg.

```
John Doe: Mary Ann. Are Married/
John Doe Mary Ann Are Married
```

I am totally unaware of macros. Any leads are appreciated!

Comment: use the formula `=SUBSTITUTE()` to replace the delimiters in both cells with nothing, then compare.

Comment: How many delimiters are we talking? just the three shown?

Comment: Yes. Only the ones shown.

Comment: @JNevill I finally ended up using the Substitute function.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Function CompareByLetter(t1 As String, t2 As String) As Boolean
CompareByLetter = CleanString(t1) = CleanString(t2)
End Function
Function CleanString(t As String) As String
Dim t1, x, c
For x = 1 To Len(t)
    c = Asc(UCase(Mid(t, x, 1)))
    If (c >= 65 And c <= 90) Or c = 32 Then t1 = t1 & Mid(t, x, 1)
Next x
CleanString = t1
End Function
```

Then you can use it as a formula:

`=CompareByLetter(A1,A2)`

This macro just compares strings by only keeping letters and spaces.

You can also use `=CleanString(A1)` to remove all other characters from your strings.

To use this in your project, open excel and press `ALT+F11`

Right click off to the left side and select `Insert -> Module`

Paste the code into the module window on the right (see attached).

[image: VBA Window]

[Image mirror since Stackoverflow image hosting seems down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjZST.png)

After that, you should be able to use the functions as you would a formula.

Just enter `=CompareByLetter(A1,A2)` in a cell.

Comment: I added as an answer just because.  I prefer your method.  You may want to explain where to put the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Office 365 Excel then we can use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(((CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)))>=65)*(CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)))<=90))+(CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)))=32),MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1),""))=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(((CODE(UPPER(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2))),1)))>=65)*(CODE(UPPER(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2))),1)))<=90))+(CODE(UPPER(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2))),1)))=32),MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A2))),1),""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: @user1274820 you need Office 365 Excel.  TEXTJOIN is a relatively new function.

Comment: @user1274820 see here for a UDF that mimics the use of TEXTJOIN(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell