# vlookup with multiple resulting values

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a table array that looks like this:

```
A   B
1   2
1   3
1   9
2   3
2   4
2   11
2   23
2   56
3   7
4   13
```

My VLOOKUP formula is to check for 1 in column A and then return the corresponding B value. Is there anyway I can get all the values for 1? Currently it just returns back the last corresponding number for 1 i.e. 9 in column B.

Comment: the return; should it be in one cell or multiples cells?

Comment: @ScottCraner doesnt matter

Comment: Well it does, because in multiple cells, just filter the table on the desired criteria.  in the same cell see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell

Comment: im not entirely sure by what you mean as to filtering it?

Comment: I want all the values for 1 then 2 and so on.... the entire data set is around 2000 values

Comment: Please show what you want for your final output.  Otherwise it is hard for us to answer what you want.

Comment: Sorry just realised a pivot table would solve my problem! thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can Pivot that data, or you can try `INDEX` and `MATCH` together, perhaps even an `IF` command with it.