# Excel If statement return multiple names

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a statement for the following problem. I have a Sheet that has the `date` and a `name`. The sheet has dates from everyday but i want to return the name of the person that is to the right 1 column of the date I am asking for.
In `Sheet 2` i have the `date` that i Type in. (What I am trying to say) `If any dates in Column 1 in sheet 1 "Date" = the date i enter in Sheet 2, provide the names in Column 2 of sheet 1. The tough part is there are multiple names in this sheet I am trying to return for the same date. Any suggestions?

Comment: Excel lookup functions like VLookup or Index/Match will only return one matched value. If you want to return multiple matches, you will need custom VBA.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell