# compare 2 string with multiple results

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

There are 2 files containing strings. The first strings in the first file are contained in the second file. So as an example there is the file which contains the following elements: table, apple and house. And in the second file there is tableleg, tabletop, applerings, applecake, and so on. Now the second file should be searched for table and the result should be the tableleg and tabletop. Is there a function for it or is Excel VBA needed?

I tried it with the following `=VLOOKUP("*C3*";'File2'!A:A;1;0)`. That works well only unfortunately he only gives me one result per element.

Comment: for the return to one cell see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell

Comment: You could use ADO and SQL to achieve this.