# Concatenate strings and remove excess comma

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate multiple strings and separate them by comma, 
and then subsequently to remove excess, leading and trailing commata.

For example, with an input of `TEST("", "b", "c", "", "")`, I would like to get
`b, c`

However, my regex `,$| ,+|^,` does not really take repeated commas into account:

```
Function TEST(a, b, c, d, e)
    res = a & ", " & b & ", " & c & ", " & d & ", " & e

    Debug.Print (res)
    Dim regex As Object, str, result As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
      .Pattern = ",$| ,+|^,"
    End With

    Dim ReplacePattern As String
    ReplacePattern = ""

    res = regex.Replace(res, ReplacePattern)

    TEST = res
End Function
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you have Office 365, TEXTJOIN does this automatically.

Comment: If not, here is some code that mimics it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell

Comment: don't have TEXTJOIN, unfortunately

Comment: Yes you do! See Scott's second comment (nice work).

Comment: Yes, I see. Just figuring out how to put my function arguments into an array, `res = TEXTJOIN(",", True, {a,b,c,d,e})` does not work...

Comment: Just a quick note, in your example, it's supposed to say "I would like to get `b`, `c`", right?

Comment: Oh yes! Will correct

Comment: One more thing I'm slightly confused about. Is the argument in your `TEST` function supposed to be a `ParamArray` of arguments or one large `String` ?

Comment: Perhaps try `TEXTJOIN(",", True, array("a","b","c","d","e"))`.

Comment: vba call: `res = TEXTJOIN(",",True,Array(a,b,c,d,e))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most elegant is @ScottCraner's suggestion of [`TEXTJOIN`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/textjoin.php) *(will remove this part of answer, if he wishes to post this as his own)*

```
Private Function nonEmptyFields(ParamArray strings() As Variant) As String
    nonEmptyFields = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, Array(strings))
End Function
```

[image]

> **Note:** This will only work for Office 365+, but you can always [create your own version of
>   `TEXTJOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell)

---

Another option would be to loop over the `ParamArray` of strings and add them together, depending on their content (whether they are populated or empty)

```
Private Function nonEmptyFields(ParamArray strings() As Variant) As String

    Dim result As String
    Dim i As Byte

    For i = LBound(strings) To UBound(strings)
        If Len(strings(i)) <> 0 Then
            If result = vbNullString Then
                result = strings(i)
            Else
                result = result & "," & strings(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    nonEmptyFields = result

End Function
```

Both would yield desired result with set up of

```
    Debug.Print nonEmptyFields(a, b, c, d, e, f) ' "", "b", "c", "", "", ""
```

[image]

Comment: Too lazy today to answer.  I like this, simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

My ugly solution maintaining the same parameters:

```
Function TEST(a, b, c, d, e)

    If a <> "" Then res = a

    If b <> "" Then
        If res <> "" Then
            res = res & ", " & b
        Else
            res = b
        End If
    End If

    If c <> "" Then
        If res <> "" Then
            res = res & ", " & c
        Else
            res = c
        End If
    End If

    If d <> "" Then
        If res <> "" Then
            res = res & ", " & d
        Else
            res = d
        End If
    End If

    If e <> "" Then
        If res <> "" Then
            res = res & ", " & e
        Else
            res = e
        End If
    End If

    TEST = res

End Function
```

[image: img1]

Comment: I feel like it would be a better idea to do this with dynamic amount of arguments (either the MS way of many `Optional` arguments or a `ParamArray`)

Comment: Definitely - if I could loop through the parameters that'd be great, I'm just keeping it the way they had it setup initially.

Comment: Technically you can, if you were to name the arguments in form of an ordered list (eg. `Optional ByVal string1 As String, Optional ByVal string2 As String, ...`  then you can just loop over the variable names with a `for` loop and `IsMissing()`. But yeah, probably more hassle than it's worth, especially if all that can be solved with one simple `ParamArray`