# How to find the sr. No where subject is equal to 1? For example if Subject is Hindi then invoke Sr. No where field=1?

Tags: excel-formula

Following is the table in Excel

```
Sr. No  English Hindi   Physics Maths
1       1       0       1       0
2       0       1       0       1
3       1       1       1       1
4       0       1       0       1
5       0       0       0       1
6       1       1       1       0
7       0       0       1       1
8       1       0       0       0
9       0       0       1       1
10      1       1       1       1
```

I want to display all Sr. No where Subject=1. For example if Subject=Physics then display Sr No. `1,3,6,7,9,10`

Comment: Use `TEXTJOIN()`

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 Excel then use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(INDEX($A$1:$E$11,0,MATCH($H$2,$A$1:$E$1,0))=1,$A$1:$A$11,""))
```

This finds the correct column and then iterates finding the `1` and returns the number in column A where `1` was found.

[image]

---

If you do not have Office 365 then look at my answer on [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell) for a vba function that mimics TEXTJOIN.

Put that code in a module and use the formula as described above.