# How to concatenate values into distinct comma separated values in excel

Tags: excel-formula

```
Name    Class1  Class2  Class3  Class4
XYZ LLC INC1    INC2    INC1    
ABC Inc INC4    INC1    INC2    INC1
ZZZ InC INC
```

Result

```
Name    Combine
XYZ LLC INC1,INC2
ABC Inc INC4,INC1,INC2
ZZZ Inc INC
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B2:E2)
```

[image]

Comment: I am using 2016 excel and it has no Textjoin function, do you know any other function?

Comment: Nope, you will need vba.  See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell) for a UDF that you can put in a module and then use the Formula above.