# Excel formula to show comma separate result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to write back a sequence of numbers in a comma separated value in a single cell. In the example below the formula would look at column A and find the reference 1, then search columns B to F and store the value. Then it would need to look back at column A and if it found the reference of 1 again and search column B to F again and add that value to the previous answer - all in one cell. Any ideas!?

[image: Image1]

Answer (score 2):

You can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula, Put this in G2:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(($A$2:$A$12=A2)*($B$2:$F$12<>""),$B$2:$F$12,""))
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  then copy down.

[image]

---

TEXTJOIN was introduced in Office 365 and Office 19, if one does not have TEXTJOIN there is code [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell) that mimics the TEXTJOIN

Comment: You are on a roll with these formula questions :)

Comment: @BigBen a bunch of softball questions.  i should have found the duplicates and closed them, but that would take longer.

Comment: Hi, any idea why I am getting this error@ https://imgur.com/cjgpha0

Comment: @user114790 see last paragraph.  You do not have TEXTJOIN as a native formula.  You will need to put the code that is linked in a module then you can use the formula.