# Select a range and then concatenate

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a range, and then concatenate. I've scoured posts talking about UDFs, using join/concat/transpose/etc.

```vb
Sub ConcatThings()
    Dim str() As String
    Dim myRng As Range
    Set myRng = Application.Selection
    Set myRng = Application.InputBox("Select range of Stuff", "Select Stuff", "Maker of things", myRng.Address, Type:=8)

    For Each myCell In myRng
        If Len(myCell) Then
            str = Join(myCell, ",")
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("general_report").Cells(2, 7) = str
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I'd like to print the values to the general_report sheet in cell 2,7.

I get a

> Cant assign to array

It highlights

```
str = Join(myCell, ",")
```

Here is a mockup of the sheet (all values were pulled out of the air)

```
_| A  | B  | C  | D  | E  | 
1|Jan | 2  | Grn| OSX|Bird|
2|Mar | 4  | Blu| PC |Frog|
3|Feb | 6  | Red| OSX|Dogs|
4|Nov | 0  | Wht| And|Cats|
5|Jun | 1  | Ylw| iOS|Worm|
```

When you run the macro, you would select whichever column is in question, and it would print the following in cell 2,7  Grn,Blu,Red,Wht,Ylw

Comment: `Join` returns a `String`, not an array of strings.... but I would suggest taking a look at this [TEXTJOIN UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell) for an already existing approach to do what you want.

Comment: What is `Join(myCell, ",")` supposed to do? It doesn't make obvious sense to join together the contents in a single cell.

Comment: @John, from what I understood, I was looping through all the cells selected from the InputBox, joining the content with a "," character and then adding it to cell 2,7.

Comment: Seems like you not interested in returning a `Range` object at `Set myRng` but an array of values instead. That variable is then ready to be joined using `Join()`. See link provided by Ben, you could even toss in `SpecialCells` to prevent a loop over non-empty cells.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Your `InputBox` is ill-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, this is a straightforward `TEXTJOIN` situation, though it is complicated by your apparent need to not join potentially blank cells in the selected range. As @JvdV mentions, using `SpecialCells` is one way to address that complication, or you could more naively do something like:

```
Sub ConcatThings()
    Dim str() As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim myRng As Range, myCell As Range

    Set myRng = Selection
    Set myRng = Application.InputBox("Select range of Stuff", "Select Stuff", myRng.Address, Type:=8)

    ReDim str(1 To myRng.Cells.count)

    For Each myCell In myRng
        If Len(myCell.Value) > 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            str(n) = myCell.Value 
        End If
    Next myCell
    ReDim Preserve str(1 To n)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("general_report").Cells(2, 7).Value = Join(str, ",")
End Sub
```

Note that the assignment to `Cells(2,7)` goes outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. Your answer works. I'd like to understand a bit more if you dont mind. Could you expand on two comments? 
The first, "it is complicated by your apparent need to not join potentially blank cells in the selected range" as I am not sure where/how I implied that in the original code? The second, "your InputBox is ill-formed" What exactly is ill-formed about it? The majority of it from what I saw was optional from what I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox

Comment: @DevNull - check the arguments... `"Maker of things"` seems in the wrong place.

Comment: @BigBen I think you are correct, I should not have entered data there for the sake of 'filling' out the blank text box when it is drawn.