# Concat list in excel issue

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, concatenation

I want to concat a list in the excel.
using this

```
=CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(J2:J9)&",")
```

[image]

J is the column of the list (J2 to J9) . K is where the concat takes place.
But the results shown above, it is not e.g. a,b,c,d,f,da,a,sd  ??

Help please has been trying to figure out whole day

Comment: what you are trying to achieve i really do not understand? and if you could provide sample file that will be great

Comment: @Hafiz    a,b,c,d,f,da,a,sd in the K column

Comment: `CONCATENATE()` does not take an array and implicit intersection will only return the 1st value. Use `TEXTJOIN()` instead > `=TEXTJOIN(",",,J2:J9)`.

Comment: @JvdV i dont think textjoin is available in excel 2016?

Comment: No it isn't, only from Excel 2019 onwards. You can look into an [UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532855/9758194), or spell all arguments out in `CONCATENATE()` > `=CONCATENATE(J2,",",J3,","....etc)`

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use this UDF function for Excel 2016.

```
=CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(J2:J9,",")
```

[image]

```
Function CONCATENATEMULTIPLE(Ref As Range, Separator As String) As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Result As String
For Each Cell In Ref
 Result = Result & Cell.Value & Separator
Next Cell
CONCATENATEMULTIPLE = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
End Function
```