# How to match comma separated list then use index to get comma separated result in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have look up table:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple |
| B | Banana |

The I have column as

| A |
| --- |
| A |
| A,B |
| B |

I like the result to show as

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple |
| A,B | Apple, Banana |
| B | Banana |

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Maybe providing screenshots or tabular data would help.

Comment: If you don't have Office 365, you can do this with Power Query or VBA. Please indicate your Excel version and if you have the `TEXTJOIN` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with a formula one must have TEXTJOIN which is available in Office365 and Excel 2019.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(D1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),A:B,2,FALSE))
```

[image]

If one does not have TEXTJOIN, vba or many helper columns will be necessary.

using vba one can create a TEXTJOIN look-a-like.  See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532855/4851590) for one.

We would also need to shift to an INDEX MATCH:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(D1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),A:A,0)))))
```

And this would need to be confirmed using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Only have excel 2016, tried to use the TEXTJOIN function, however, still don't know how to get the final result, get error in value

Comment: Thank you so much, Scott, it worked. Could you please explain a bit about N, IF({1}...) part? when I only use FilterXML on A,B itself, it only returns A, so how did it returned an array?

Comment: The filterxml returns an array, but if you only put it in one cell it will only return the first.  A cell cannot hold an array.  the `N(IF({1}...))` is a little loop hole to force INDEX to accept the array of numbers returned.  In older versions INDEX will not naturally accept arrays.

Comment: Also, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.