# concatenate formula formation of multiple cells into one cell

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to concatenate the text of multiple cells into one cells where there is blank cells too, for blank cells it is taking '0' which i want to be blank eg.,

- Cell 1 : Blank
- Cell 2 : Blank
- Cell 3 : A
- Cell 4 : B
- Cell 5 : Blank
- Cell 6 : C
- Cell 7 : Blank
- Cell 8 : D

answer should be ABCD without any zeros.

Comment: What is the formula you are using? If using `TEXTJOIN`. there's an argument to ignore empty cells. If your version of Excel doesn't support `TEXTJOIN`, there's a VBA equivalent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell).

Comment: If you can't use `TEXTJOIN`, `=A1&A2&A3&A4&A5&A6&A7&A8` may work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach if you have Excel 365:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:H1)
```

OR

```
{=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISTEXT(A1:H1),A1:H1,""))}
```

If do not have Excel 365 then:

```
= CONCATENATE(
IF(COUNTBLANK(B1)=1,"",B1&CHAR(10)&","),
IF(COUNTBLANK(C1)=1,"",C1&CHAR(10)&","),
IF(COUNTBLANK(D1)=1,"",D1&CHAR(10)&","),
IF(COUNTBLANK(E1)=1,"",E1&CHAR(10)&","),
IF(COUNTBLANK(F1)=1,"",F1&CHAR(10)&","),
IF(COUNTBLANK(G1)=1,"",G1&CHAR(10)&","),
IF(COUNTBLANK(H1)=1,"",H1&CHAR(10)&","),
IF(COUNTBLANK(I1)=1,"",I1&CHAR(10)&","),
IF(COUNTBLANK(J1)=1,"",J1&CHAR(10))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1** through **A8**, pick a cell and enter:

```
=A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & A5 & A6 & A7 & A8
```

[image]