# Merge values of column B based on common values on column A

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, how I can merge values of `Column B` based on common values on `Column A`?

Basically what I need is some thing like this

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Does your actual data have a title row?

Comment: I am using Excel Plus 2016

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582741/excel-return-range-of-values-based-on-criteria for a UDF that will return the concatenation.

Comment: Thanks Scot , but this s a little bit different that what you recommended as I do not have any hard coded string like "approved"

Comment: The formula in  C2 would be: `=IF(A2<>A1,TEXTJOINIFS(B:B,", ",A:A,A2),"")`

Comment: C1 of your example would just be the `TEXTJOINIFS(B:B,", ",A:A,A2)` part

Comment: Actually use this one in C1 and copy down: `=IF(MATCH(A1,A:A,0)=ROW(A1),TEXTJOINIFS(B:B,", ",A:A,A1),"")`  It will work if the data is sorted or not and only put the output in the first occurrence of the value in column A.

Comment: Mona: you have easily been here enough to know that unresearched questions are discouraged here.

Comment: I would additionally note (again) that your questions still are not of a particularly good quality. Your English seems fine to me, so you have completely understood the several requests for technical writing that have been made to you - you have just chosen to ignore them, so that you can beg, bow, scrape and plead in your posts instead. That is not ideal for the site, as it takes volunteer editors away from fixing problems in other posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this UDF:

```
Function TEXTJOINIFS(rng As Range, delim As String, ParamArray arr() As Variant)
    Dim rngarr As Variant
    rngarr = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Value

    Dim condArr() As Boolean
    ReDim condArr(1 To Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange).Rows.Count) As Boolean


    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2
        Dim colArr() As Variant
        colArr = Intersect(arr(i), arr(i).Parent.UsedRange).Value
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(colArr, 1) To UBound(colArr, 1)

            If Not condArr(j) Then
                Dim charind As Long
                charind = Application.Max(InStr(arr(i + 1), ">"), InStr(arr(i + 1), "<"), InStr(arr(i + 1), "="))
                Dim opprnd As String
                If charind = 0 Then
                    opprnd = "="
                Else
                    opprnd = Left(arr(i + 1), charind)
                End If
                Dim t As String
                t = """" & colArr(j, 1) & """" & opprnd & """" & Mid(arr(i + 1), charind + 1) & """"
                If Not Application.Evaluate(t) Then condArr(j) = True
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = LBound(rngarr, 1) To UBound(rngarr, 1)
        If Not condArr(i) Then
            TEXTJOINIFS = TEXTJOINIFS & rngarr(i, 1) & delim
        End If
    Next i

    TEXTJOINIFS = Left(TEXTJOINIFS, Len(TEXTJOINIFS) - Len(delim))

End Function
```

You would call it like this:

```
=IF(MATCH(A1,A:A,0)=ROW(A1),TEXTJOINIFS(B:B,", ",A:A,A1),"")
```

Now it does not matter if the data is sorted or not it will only put the output in column C where the value in Column A first appears.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scot but `=IF(MATCH(A1,A:A,0)=ROW(A1),TEXTJOINIFS(B:B,", ",A:A,A1),"")` it is not working I am getting the `#NAME?` error

Comment: You have to put the code above in a module. Then it will work just like any formula.

Comment: I added the code in a Module but same thing is happening

Comment: Did you put it in a general module or the worksheet code?  If it is in a general Module it should work.  The above examples are using that code unmodified.  I placed it in a module and then used the formula as described.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my untested code of course.
The code below uses 2 loops to add the information.

```
dim X as integer
dim X2 as integer

dim match as string

X = 1

do while sheets("sheet1").range("A" & X).value <> ""

    sheets("sheet1").range("C" & X).value = sheets("sheet1").range("B" & X).value
    match = sheets("sheet1").range("A" & X).value        
    X2 = X + 1

        do while sheets("sheet1").range("A" & X2).value = match

            sheets("sheet1").range("C" & X).value = sheets("sheet1").range("C" & X).value + ", " + sheets("sheet1").range("B" & X2).value 
            X2 = X2 + 1

        loop

    X = X2
    X = X + 1

Loop
```

Comment: If you format it with proper cases and indentations, then - why not? 

Comment: Ok I get your point - it was a lazy answer @JohnyL - I have made the edits and added the variable declarations :)

Comment: Ok, earned for efforts ))

Comment: Thanks @JohnyL you have officially welcomed me to the community my rep was 14 and this was my first answer :)

Comment: Jonathan: it's OK to let new users know that we have voting/acceptance systems here, but in general we would rather people did not ask for votes. If you create good material, votes will come organically.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A$1:A$15=A1,B$1:B$15,""))
```

(Use CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER instead of ENTER to enter the formula)

Comment: I do not think Excel Plus 2016 has TEXTJOIN

Comment: Looks like Scott is right I cant' find `TEXTJOIN` here

Comment: @MonaCoder I do have a UDF that mimics the regular TEXTJOIN also.  It can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell