# Search and combine multiple values from an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There is a data set with cells containing multiple values.
I need to cross check each cell in the dataset with a predetermined list of values and return all matching values in one cell per row.

[image]

The best option would be to use TEXTJOIN function but it doesn't work in my Excel 2016. Here is the alternative code I tried to make but it returns only the first value in the array.

```
{=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(list,A2))), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(list,A2)), list, ""), "")}
```

Will greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: With out TEXTJOIN you will need vba

Comment: Have a look here for a udf for TEXTJOIN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell  and look here for a TEXTJOINIFS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a

Comment: The only way to do it with formula is if your `list` is finite and you test each one in a separate Search and concatenate each search,  In your example you would string together three Search functions, one for each item in the list.  This gets unruly with long lists.

Comment: My list is pretty long - 53 values and it can aslo be increased later..

Comment: Then VBA either as a UDF like I linked to or a sub will be needed.

Comment: Your TEXTJOIN Formula would be `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(list,A2)),list,""))` entered as an array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Put the code from the first link in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The same has been answered through comments by Scott Craner, hence the same is in unanswered history. Behalf of Scott posting answer here which have accepted by question owner.

Your `TEXTJOIN` Formula would be `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(list,A2)),list,""))` entered as an array formula with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`. Put the code from the first link in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula