# Remove first concat to empty string

Tags: excel, vba

currently with the codes below, output would be `~ abc~ etc~ etc~`. How do I remove the first **~**. So it should start with **abc** straight away, not **~**.

```
Function SpecialLookup(lookup_value As String, src_rng As Range, column_index As Long)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String
    xResult = ""
    For Each rng In src_rng
        If rng = lookup_value Then
            xResult = xResult & "~ " & rng.Offset(0, column_index - 1).Value
        End If
    Next
    SpecialLookup = xResult
End Function
```

Comment: BTW  `TEXTJOIN` will do this if one has it.

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah, sadly, i do not have it. But thank you! Just saw your answer :) helps alot

Comment: here is code that mimics TEXTJOIN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell

Comment: And here is a TEXTJOINIFS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a

Comment: great! thanks so much, will keep this post archived; useful for future use!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Mid` should do the trick

---

```
SpecialLookup = Mid(xResult, 3, Len(xResult))
```

Comment: in vba the third criterion is optional you can get the same with `SpecialLookup = Mid(xResult, 2)` and I believe it should `SpecialLookup = Mid(xResult, 3)` as the prefix is `'~ '`

Comment: @ScottCraner good catch on the leading space. I did not know VBA defaults to full length of string. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Hey urdeaboy and scott craner! Thanks so much to both! works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I like this pattern:

```
Function SpecialLookup(lookup_value As String, src_rng As Range, column_index As Long)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String, sep as String
    For Each rng In src_rng
        If rng = lookup_value Then
            xResult = xResult & sep & rng.Offset(0, column_index - 1).Value
            sep = "~ " '<<<<<
        End If
    Next
    SpecialLookup = xResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

another option is an IF:

```
Function SpecialLookup(lookup_value As String, src_rng As Range, column_index As Long)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String
    xResult = ""
    For Each rng In src_rng
        If rng = lookup_value Then
            If xResult = "" Then
                xResult = rng.Offset(0, column_index - 1).Value
            Else
                xResult = xResult & "~ " & rng.Offset(0, column_index - 1).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SpecialLookup = xResult
End Function
```