# Join text from multiple rows based on common attribute in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, concatenation, textjoin

I have a table of data in Excel that has a `company ID` in one column and a `NAICS code` in another column. Only one NAICS code can be entered per row. Within the table a company ID can appear more than once with the same or a different NAICS code.

In a separate table (tab) I have a list of unique company IDs with a separate column called `NAICS codes`. I want to create a formula that lists all NAICS codes belonging to a company in a string in that field.

Table 1

```
Company ID  NAICS Code
1   334
1   334
2   311
2   3231
2   311
3   311
3   311
3   336390
4   331110 
5   311821
6   311821
4   336411
3   3115
```

Table 2

```
Company ID  NAICS Codes
1   334
2   311, 3231
3   311, 336390
4   331110, 31110, 336411
5   311821
6   311821
```

Comment: Do you have access to the TEXTJOIN formula?

Comment: See, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a

Comment: or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell

Comment: Yes I have access to Text Join

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=A2)))`