# Check cell against multiple others, Output Matches "," Delimited

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Data

```
SKU Cell (M5) 
SKU Check Range(Table 1, Column J2:J8000) 
Model Range(F2:F8000)
```

I need to have the following logic converted to the formula for it

> IF SKU = SKU Check, Output all models that match from Model Column
> with ", " delimiters for multiple matches

I hope this makes sense
Any help on this would be incredibly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Office 365 use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(F2:F8000,J2:J8000 = M5,""))
```

Without O365, vba will be needed.  There are many UDF that mimic TEXTJOIN in which one can use an Array IF() to return the correct values.  Here is one:

[VLOOKUP with multiple criteria returning values in one cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell)

Or this one that does TEXTJOINIFS:

[Merge values of column B based on common values on column A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a)

Comment: Absolutely spot on Scott as always, really appreciate the help on this!

Comment: Out of interest, how complicated would it be to change this to the first occurrence of the Model, currently I've got a lot of duplicate model data being output :/ Im using O365 btw

Comment: not sure I am understanding your request.

Comment: Might be best as a new question but essentially, the TextJoin is creating this: Alpha,Alpha,Alpha,Alpha, Beta, Beta, Charlie. If it can be done, I just want it to say Alpha, Beta, Charlie and ignore the duplicate occurrences of the model. If a new questions best then ill make one

Comment: Oh, wrap the filter in UNIQUE: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(F2:F8000,J2:J8000 = M5,"")))`

Comment: Absolute legend. Thats it! Thanks so much dude, really appreciate it