# How to merge two rows in a which has same values in other columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel with values like below

[image]

The last Column alone has different values, They are in fact url of images.

How do I merge those values with commas or any separator?

Comment: Could you copy/paste to word document, use the find and replace function to replace "https" with "; https" and then replace all? Once that happens, merge the cells and copy/paste back into excel?

Comment: here is a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a

Comment: You can use Power Query. `GroupBy` the identical columns with `Operation: All Rows`. Then turn the grouped table into a list and extract the list with your desired separator.

Comment: @ScottCraner I followed the steps in that answer, It doesn't work. I pasted the code `=IF(MATCH(A1,A:A,0)=ROW(A1),TEXTJOINIFS(E:E,", ",A:A,A1),"")` in the formula, and pasted the UDF into the macro. All am seeing Invalid Outside Procedure. Am using MS Office Professional Plus 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to `FILTER`, `UNIQUE`, and `TEXTJOIN`:

---

1. `G1 = UNIQUE(A1:D6)`
2. `K1 = TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(E1:E6,(A1:A6=G1)*(B1:B6=H1)*(C1:C6=I1)*(D1:D6=J1)))`

[image]

Comment: I have 838 Cells, So I should type in `G1=UNIQUE(A1:D838)` , right?

Comment: I don't find UNIQUE anywhere.

Comment: Ok, This worked so well., I just had to move the sheet to google spreadsheets in order for the formulas to work.