# Using a function to look up and concatenate data

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I have one worksheet `Relationships` which contains data entries specifying a relationship between A and B and some related data.

In another worksheet, I have rows for each A and would like a cell that effectively queries the `Relationships` data and summarizes all B who have a relationship with A (and some of the related data).

I have written a VBA lookup to do this, but I imagine it is the least efficient approach possible, as it loops through the entire range in `Relationships`, determines if the subject row is one relating to A, and if it is, it starts concatenating a string which it ultimately returns.

Just wanted to know if anyone can point me in the right direction for an approach to this problem that is hopefully more efficient? `VLOOKUP` doesn't seem to be very helpful because of the "multiple match" issue.

As requested, an example of what I used - it works fine, but I fear it is slow and will become crippling as the data grows.

```
Function oLookup(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, entity As Long, addlbylines As Long, name As Long, title As Long, Optional count As Variant)
Dim x As Range
Dim result As String
result = ""
For Each x In lookuprange.Rows
    If (x.Cells(1, entity).Value = lookupval And lookupval <> "") Then
        result = result & x.Cells(1, name) & " (" & x.Cells(1, title) & ")"
        If Not IsMissing(count) Then result = result & " [Freq: " & x.Cells(1, count) & "]"
        result = result & Chr(10)
    End If
Next x

If result = "" Then result = "No data" Else result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
oLookup = result
End Function
```

Comment: Please include the vba you tried.

Comment: Added it to the post.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a

Comment: This is a bit beyond my level and will probably take a bit of time to pick apart and understand. I can see from the output that it can probably be adapted to what I am trying to do - is it faster as well?

Comment: much as it uses variant arrays instead of the actual range.  And in your case you would just use: `=TEXTJOINIFS(Relationships!B:B,CHAR(10),Relationships!A:A,A2)`

Comment: Thanks, I think I will need to study it - as you can see from the above code I am trying to pull from different columns in the row to construct a slightly more involved concatenation, like: Item1Field 1 (Item1Field 2), Item2Field1 (Item2Field2) , ...

Comment: Then look how I moved the ranges into variant arrays and looped those.  do not loop ranges it is slow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229226/discussion-between-user973066-and-scott-craner).