# Logical operators as parameters in UDF (similar to sumif function) - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard, logical-operators

I want to create a UDF (user defined function) similar to Sumif below.

```
  =SUMIF(F10:F15,">20")
```

But how do I use the string parameter ">20" in the if statement.  I tried

```
  If (A Like ConditionalString) Then
```

But it is working for wildcards and not for the logical operators.  I need it work for both wildcards and logical operators as well.

Comment: Look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a)  where I did a TEXTJOINIFS and you can see how I did it.

Comment: The basics, is that you need to test whether the opperands are there and if not put `=` in front and use `Application.Evaluate` to test if true or not.  And if you want wildcards you will need to test for those and use like instead.  But the main thing is that you will need to do the branching and logical path.

Comment: What specific wildcards and what specific operators?