# Macro Works on my computer but gets Run-Time Error '438' on other computers

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA and I made a macro that has been working on my computer, but when I sent it to someone else, it errors out on this line:

```
If WorksheetFunction.Concat(ActiveSheet.Range("a2:n2").Value) <> "UnitOper UnitDeptProjectDateLine DescrAmountAccountProductJournal IDLine #RefStatusAffiliate" Then
```

I will include the entire macro below but I am trying to open a file using getopenfilename and make sure that the file has the correct content. Even when I sent the macro to people using excel 2016, it still doesnt work and errors out.

I tried something new and now it says type mismatch on the same line.

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


 Dim myFileName As Variant
 Dim sWorkbook, i As String
 Dim Macrotool As String
 Dim Countlines As Long




Macrotool = ActiveWorkbook.Name
myFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename

If myFileName <> False Then
Workbooks.Open (myFileName)
sWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveSheet.Range("O2") = "=concat(a2:n2)"



If ActiveSheet.Range("o2").Value <> "UnitOper UnitDeptProjectDateLine DescrAmountAccountProductJournal IDLine #RefStatusAffiliate" Then

    Workbooks(sWorkbook).Close False
    i = MsgBox("It looks like you are uploading the wrong file." & vbLf & "Please make sure you are using one of the following queries:" & vbLf & "" & vbLf & "'ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY_ANY_CF'" & vbLf & "'ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY_BU'" & vbLf & "'ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY_BU_OP'" & vbLf & "'ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY_BU_OP_DEP'" & vbLf & "'ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY_BU_OP_DEP_PRJ'", vbOKOnly, "Wrong Filed Used")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Workbooks(Macrotool).Activate
    Sheets("Home").Select
    GoTo OnError
End If
```

Comment: I stopped scrolling through your code for fear of developing RSI ;)

Comment: Not directly related to that specific error, but ...[nonetheless obligatory read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) <~ you *need* to read this, carefully.

Comment: Avoid using `ActiveSomething` and precisely define your variables.  Check **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/2687063)** for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You are using fancy Excel version of 2016 and the "others" are using Excel 2013 or lower? Thus, they do not have `WorksheetFunction.Concat` and they get error 438.

The one that told you that they are using `Excel 2016` and still get an error there are either not sure which version they are using or are getting error somewhere else.

**Worst case scenario** - go to those people with Excel 2016 and make sure that they are having exactly the same worksheet with exactly the same error on that line. Make sure that you check the `ActiveSheet` name as well.

Comment: FWIW If the error is exactly where OP claims it is, this answer isn't a guess, it *is* the answer.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Thanks! :) I am using 2013 and I got the exactly same error, using `WorksheetFunction.Concat()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an SO Q&A somewhere that has a UDF implementation of the `Concat` function that can be used in place of the Excel 2016 function.

Comment: Do only some versions of Excel 2016 have WorksheetFunction.Concat?

Comment: @jmartin0807 - that would be an interesting "feature" in Excel. So I guess, no. Every version should have it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572697/udf-to-concatenate-values

Comment: @jmartin0807 I don't know that but I strongly suspect the answer is "nope". In any case if you mean to fix your problem you'll need to concatenate the cell values yourself. See ^^^^ this post ^^^^.

Comment: I tried to fix it in a different way but now it is saying Type Mismatch. See updated question :) Also, it still works for me when I run it, but my coworker who has office 2016 now has a type mismatch error on that same line.

Comment: @Mat'sMug forgot to tag you

Comment: @jmartin0807 - try some simple debugging. Like `msgbox ActiveSheet.Range("o2").Value` The `O2` should be an error, in order to give `Type Mismatch`. And the problem should be somewhere in the active sheets. E.g., the `ActiveSheet` for you is not the `ActiveSheet` for your colleague.

Comment: @jmartin0807 note that "chameleon questions" that change with every helpful answer are frowned upon. SO isn't a debugging service, the Q&A's primarily help people searching for solutions to similar problems. That type mismatch is a classic, already answered multiple times over.